# Laravel React MySQL Routing Issue

Tags: reactjs, laravel-5, routes, http-status-code-404

I am trying to make it so that I can register a user but I am getting a 404 error, assuming that means that react is unable to find the route established by the api.php file, is there anything else that I am missing? I have already set it in the package.json file that the proxy is set to "localhost:8000" (the port I chose to use for laravel's backend stuff). I am confused on why it's  not hitting this route upon submitting. I feel like I'm close but I am new to using php as the backend so any insight would be helpful.

I am also creating something where the user is able to play music on the app, so there is a route for that labeled "shop", and that does not work for the sole reason that I have not set that route up (also gives a 404 error).

Below are my api routes that I am trying to get react to detect

```
<?php

Route::post('register','UserController@register');
Route::post('login','UserController@login');
Route::post('profile','UserController@getAuthenticatedUser');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function(Request $request){
    return $request->user();
});

?>
```

And this is the React portion of my registration file.

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { register } from './UserFunctions';

class Register extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

    this.state = {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errors: {},
    }

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
}

onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const newUser = {
        name: this.state.first_name + ' ' + this.state.last_name,
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
    }

    register(newUser).then(res => {
        if (res) {
            this.props.history.push('/login')
        }
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx auto">
                    <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-wieght-normal">
                            Register
                        </h1>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <label htmlFor="first_name">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name" value={this.state.first_name} onChange={this.onChange} />

                            <label htmlFor="last_name">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name" value={this.state.last_name} onChange={this.onChange} />

                            <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label><br />
                            <input type="email" className="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChange} />
                            <br />
                            <label htmlFor="password">Desired Password</label><br />
                            <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.onChange} />
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Register
```

I have those post routes defined, but when I press submit within my register form, I get a 404 error saying that it can't find this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show me your

```
import { register } from './UserFunctions';
```

file so that I can see the url path defined.

Assuming this route is inside your routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api', 'prefix' => 'v1'], function(){
Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@index');
});
```

and in JS file

```
    import axios from 'axios'

export const register = newUser => {
    return axios
        .post('api/v1/register', newUser,
        {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: not sure if I did what I was supposed to but I edited your thing to show what it looks like with just the registration function.

    import axios from 'axios'

    export const register = newUser => {
        return axios
            .post('/register', newUser,
                {
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }

Comment: This ended up working but I could have left it how it was. The thing I realized was that I was forgetting the "/" in front of the api/v1/register or just 'api/register', so it needed to be '/api/v1/register' or '/api/register'. Thanks a lot for helping me realize this man!